# Datadog explore facets and measures

Tags: facet, measure, datadog

We have multiple applications sending logs to `Datadog` via `syslog`. Every team has created `facets` / `measures` for their respective applications under a particular group.

Is there a direct way to explore the list of `facets` / `measures` under a specific group? I am trying to create a document for our support team to include the list of `facets` and `measures`. I am able to view them in the Log Search page, but, cannot copy.

I am looking something as export the list of `facets`/`measures` to excel / csv.

Note: I am restricted to use datadog api.

Comment: Awwwh.. I was able to copy in Edge. Chrome did not allowed selection on the UI.

Comment: if your goal is to document facets / measures that are relevant for specific support use-cases, maybe a better idea is to create "[saved views](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/saved_views/)" for those use-cases that only show the facets/measures that are relevant for them?

Comment: Did you find where the facets are? I can't find it. I want to delete some. And convert a measure to facet. Non-api, in the dashboard?

Comment: @Noitidart In logs explorer -> at the top of the facet panel (on the left) -> find your facet -> click on edit (pencil button) -> click on Delete button (bottom left). It's well explained in the [Datadog docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/facets/#delete-a-facet)